# Is there any study that tries to quantify the impact of Russian government support for anti vaccination?

Tags: russian-federation, covid-19, propaganda, vaccine

Recently, the [Russian government threatened to ban YouTube](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-58737433) if it does not reinstate two German-language channels backed by the Russian state that were deleted for violating Covid misinformation guidelines.

This suggests that the Russian government provides some support for anti-vaccination ideas.

[This article](https://humanevents.com/2021/03/23/russias-anti-vaccine-propaganda-is-tantamount-to-a-declaration-of-war/) suggests that there is virtually an entire Russian propaganda promoting anti-vaccination in the US and other Western countries.

I am wondering if there is a study that tries to quantify the influence of Russia in promoting anti-vaccination in other countries. I am thinking in estimating the order of magnitude of money spent on social media and people reached by the content.

Comment: (Not my DV) effects of propaganda in general are difficult to quantify. The EU report from April that accused China and Russia of targeting Western vaccines, speaks of "100 examples" (in Reuters [summary](https://www.reuters.com/world/china/russia-china-sow-disinformation-undermine-trust-western-vaccines-eu-report-says-2021-04-28/)) but doesn't seem to try to quantify the effect. As someone noted in a now deleted answer, Russia and China probably don't really want to undermine the basic idea of a vaccine, but they see an opportunity to promote their own.

Comment: On the other hand there is at least one pre-pandemic [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6137759/) discussing [alleged] Russian anti-vaccine messaging in the West. So perhaps they may be thinking that whatever such messaging they promote abroad (in foreign languages) it won't "come back to bite them" domestically. Hard to say really what their thinking is.

Comment: Have not seen Russia suporting anti vaccination, just blackmailing the western vaccines, which is a diferent isue.